# Android: OnClick ImageView not change correct Image

Tags: android, listview, onclick, imageview

I am creating an app where there are images in a custom Listview. The database put a picture or another. Clicking the image has to change. But when I click the image is not changed at the correct ImageView. It changes other ImageView.

I need any help. thanks

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;

    final MonumentosHolder holder = new MonumentosHolder();

    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row, null);

        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textoListviewNombre);
        ImageView img3 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imagenVisto);

        holder.texto = tv;
        holder.imagenVisto = img3;

        v.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (MonumentosHolder) v.getTag();
    }

            holder.position = position;

            final MonumentosObj p = monumentosLista.get(position);

    holder.texto.setText(p.getNombre());

    if (p.getVisto().equals("n")) {
        holder.imagenVisto.setImageResource(R.drawable.vistorojo);
    } else {
        holder.imagenVisto.setImageResource(R.drawable.vistoverde); 
    }

    holder.imagenVisto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            MonumentosObj p1 = monumentosLista.get(holder.position);

            if (p1.getVisto().equals("s")) {

                holder.imagenVisto.setImageResource(R.drawable.vistorojo);
                p1.setVisto("n");

            } else {

                holder.imagenVisto.setImageResource(R.drawable.vistoverde);
                p1.setVisto("s");

            }

            MonumentosAdapter.updateMonumentos(p1);
            MonumentosObj p = monumentosLista.get(holder.position);
        }
    });

    imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrls[position], holder.imagen, options, animateFirstListener);

    return v;
}
```

**EDIT**

Onclick not change the correct image. But when I scroll the listview to below and and return to top, the correct image has changed...

Comment: Try `holder.imagenVisto.setImageBitmap(null)` before `holder.imagenVisto.setImageResource()`

Comment: can you provide MonumentosObj class definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that bit of code maybe wrong :

```
holder.imagenVisto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    private int pos = position;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        MonumentosObj p1 = monumentosLista.get(pos);
```

Try to store position inside holder object and when assigning it in onClick Listener instead

```
 private int pos = position;
```

do

```
private int pos = holder.getPosition()
```

Remember that android ListViews are **not** loading all items at one time it just loads thats what is visible and few items beyond that,

Also remember that positions of your items in your Arrays doesn't change you may use it somehow :)

Comment: holder has not getPosition()

Answer (score 0):

try to change

```
holder.imagenVisto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
```

by

```
holder.imagenVisto.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
```

Comment: No need to do this. It will be already imported as `import android.view.OnClickListener;` otherwise it will give a compile error.

Answer (score 0):

I think your click listener affect early items in your list!

do this:

put a long item in your viewHolder:

```
class MonumentosHolder {
    .
    .
    .
    long position;
}
```

and then in your getView, set the holder  positon:

```
View v = convertView;
```

**--EDITED--**
   final MonumentosHolder holder = new MonumentosHolder();
**--END EDITED--**

```
if (convertView == null) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row, null);

    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textoListviewNombre);
    ImageView img3 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imagenVisto);

    holder.texto = tv;
    holder.imagenVisto = img3;

    v.setTag(holder);
}
else {
    holder = (MonumentosHolder) v.getTag();
}
 **holder.postion = position;**
```

and then click listener would be like this:

**EDITED**
 holder.imagenVisto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        MonumentosObj p1 = monumentosLista.get(**holder.position**);

        if (p1.getVisto().equals("s")) {

            holder.imagenVisto.setImageResource(R.drawable.vistorojo);
            p1.setVisto("n");

        } else {

            holder.imagenVisto.setImageResource(R.drawable.vistoverde);
            p1.setVisto("s");

        }

        MonumentosAdapter.updateMonumentos(p1);
        MonumentosObj p = monumentosLista.get(holder.position);
    }
});
```

**EDIT 4**
remove the final modifier from holder, define another MonumentosHolder named `finalHolder` like this:

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;

```
MonumentosHolder holder = new MonumentosHolder();

if (convertView == null) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row, null);

    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textoListviewNombre);
    ImageView img3 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imagenVisto);

    holder.texto = tv;
    holder.imagenVisto = img3;

    v.setTag(holder);
}
else {
    holder = (MonumentosHolder) v.getTag();
}

        holder.position = position;

        final MonumentosObj p = monumentosLista.get(position);

holder.texto.setText(p.getNombre());

if (p.getVisto().equals("n")) {
    holder.imagenVisto.setImageResource(R.drawable.vistorojo);
} else {
    holder.imagenVisto.setImageResource(R.drawable.vistoverde); 
}

final MonumentosHolder finalHolder = holder;
holder.imagenVisto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        MonumentosObj p1 = monumentosLista.get(finalHolder.position);

        if (p1.getVisto().equals("s")) {

            holder.imagenVisto.setImageResource(R.drawable.vistorojo);
            p1.setVisto("n");

        } else {

            holder.imagenVisto.setImageResource(R.drawable.vistoverde);
            p1.setVisto("s");

        }

        MonumentosAdapter.updateMonumentos(p1);
        MonumentosObj p = monumentosLista.get(finalHolder.position);
    }
});

imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrls[position], holder.imagen, options, animateFirstListener);

return v;
```

}

Comment: Ok! I missed this one!  MonumentosObj p = monumentosLista.get(pos); is incorrect! use this holder.position instead of pos

Comment: I think your holder should be a final variable too. I update my answer :)

Comment: nothing... my listview has 60 results, but in the screen show 4 results of the listview. always change the image below(4). if i scroll, change the fourth result

Comment: Are your changing holder.postion in getview like this: holder.postion = position;

Comment: else { holder = (MonumentosHolder) v.getTag(); } --> remove final modifier. but if i delete final, error in other holder

Comment: Could you please post your changed version of code?

Comment: You just need another holder variable that was final, SEED EDIT 4

Comment: final MonumentosHolder finalHolder = holder; --> The value of the local variable finalHolder is not used. holder.imagenVisto.setImageResource(...) --> change modifier to final

Comment: finalHolder is used inside the onClickListener, here  `MonumentosObj p1 = monumentosLista.get(finalHolder.position);` and `MonumentosObj p = monumentosLista.get(finalHolder.position);`